# adding secret key to header for rest call in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, rest

I have an HttpClient object that I'm using to make a rest call to OpenFire.  I have a key that I'm trying to attach to the header for the call.  How is this done correctly?  My attempt is shown below.  using `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("APIKEY", "theSecretKey")`

```
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Uri.UriSchemeHttps  + "://" + domain);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/xml"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("APIKEY", "theSecretKey");
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(queryString).Result;
            string stringResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Comment: does your attempt not work?

Comment: What response do you receive?

Comment: Not sure what your asking, seems like your already adding the "header".

Comment: It may be easier for debugging purposes to not use the `asynch` method

Comment: @Mike_G: I get an error tag <error>RequestNotAuthorised</error>.  This unauthorized request may be unrelated to the secretkey.  I discovered the Plugin we are using in place of Rest API will not allow connections from non-specified IP address (like what my IIS Manager is using instead of what our dev system uses)